# Failing ssh proxyjump: "Stdio forwarding request failed: Session open refused by peer"

Tags: ssh

The below is my ssh config file.

```
# ~/.ssh/config 

$ cat config

Host myproxy
HostName proxy.server.com
User proxyuser
GSSAPIAuthentication no
ControlPath /tmp/%r@%h:%p
ControlMaster auto
ControlPersist 10h

Host target
HostName target.server.com
User targetuser
ProxyJump myproxy
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
StrictHostKeyChecking no
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.service
```

When I run `ssh myproxy` on my local laptop, it succeeds.

```
$ ssh -vvv myproxy
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 2.8.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/user/.ssh/config line 10: Applying options for myproxy
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
debug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote
debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 66279
debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
proxyuser@proxy-bastion-prod:~:
```

And when I run `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.service target.server.com` on the proxy server, it succeeds too.

```
proxyuser@proxy-bastion-prod:~: ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.service targetuser@target.server.com
```

However, when I run `ssh target` on my local laptop, it fails.

```
$ ssh -vvv target
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 2.8.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/user/.ssh/config line 18: Applying options for target
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Setting implicit ProxyCommand from ProxyJump: ssh -vvv -W '[%h]:%p' target
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -vvv -W '[target.server.com]:22' target
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa.service type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa.service-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 2.8.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/user/.ssh/config line 10: Applying options for target
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
debug3: mux_client_request_stdio_fwd: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 66279
debug3: mux_client_request_stdio_fwd: stdio forward request sent
Stdio forwarding request failed: Session open refused by peer
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
```

There also exists `id_rsa.service` file on my local laptop.

I have no idea what the logs mean.

Where should I check?

Any link or comment will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since you connect to your target like

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.service target.server.com
```

providing a key. I guess you have to configure somehow on proxy side that the key will be correctly picked up when you are doing a jump.